# Python MySQL data insert

Tags: python, mysql, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a page using `python` and `beautifulsoup4`. It will output title, price, link from that page.

From these 4 for loop, I want to insert those four variables `imghref, href, name, newprice` in `MySQL` db. So I wrote some code like this :

```
    db = MySQLdb.connect("host", "root", "pass", "dbname")
    cursor = db.cursor()

    def sample(max_pages):
        page = 1
        while page <= max_pages:

            .... other lines, not related to mysql...

            for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'hoverbuy a-color'}):
                href = link.get('href')
                #print(href)

            for title in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'title ellipsis'}):
                name = title.string
                #print(name)

            for price in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'itm-price'}):
                fprice= price.get_text() 
                newprice = fprice.replace("৳", "")
                #print(newprice)

            sql = "INSERT INTO product(link, title,price) \
                      VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')" % (href, name, newprice)

            try:  
               cursor.execute(sql)
               db.commit()
            except:
               db.rollback()      

            page += 1

    sample(1)

    db.close()
```

So, when I run this code, only one row(link,title,price) is getting inserted in MySQL, while there are 70 or more of them in that page.

So, I think the `while` loop isn't running properly or I'm misplacing the `sql` query and `page += 1` loop

***But if I just print those variables it's running perfectly with all of the 70+ output***

Comment: It seems very likely that you are having an exception but your except blog does not log anything and sliently rolls back.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are running only 1 SQL query to insert only 1 row. I'm guessing it only inserts the last value on the website.

Currently you find all of the occurrences of each item on the website and replace the last in your for loop.
I suggest storing them all in a lists. then adding everything you find to a list.

```
for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'hoverbuy a-color'}):
    href.append(link.get('href'))

for title in soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'title ellipsis'}):
    name.append(title.string)

for price in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'itm-price'}):
    fprice= price.get_text() 
    newprice.append(fprice.replace("৳", ""))
```

What you might then be looking for is the executemany() method. Which allows you to put whole lists into the database. Alternatively You can check out a video I made on how to do this, [linked to specific time.](https://youtu.be/NWU5i53m60Q?t=783)

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO product VALUES(?,?,?)",(href, name, newprice))
```

Edit: You may want to be wary and make sure all your lists are the same size!

Comment: I tried these bunch of codes : https://repl.it/BPEU/2 . But nothing's working. I'm missing something you said as I'm very new. Hoping for a bit more help.

Comment: Are you getting errors? I left the list initialization out, because I assumed you would be able to change where you currently initialize them into lists.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks for your idea of working with list.

Answer (score 0):

the maxpages = 1, and while page <= maxpages, loop can be ran.
when the page+= 1, page = 2. break the loop.
so sql is only executed once.

href, name, newprice  are single value.  so  only one record. you should use executemany() to insert multi records.

Comment: That's not the problem. SQL query is inserting only one row from that given page, where there are over 70 rows.
But if I just print those variables,All those rows are printing.

Comment: href, name, newprice  are single value.  so  only one record. you should use executemany() to insert multi records.